# XMPP Query Group Chat (MUC) directory using search term

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

Creating an XMPP client, part of which involves querying the directory for chat rooms whose name matches a specific search term. Lets call this search term SEARCH.

The following XML (with the correct to/from) gives me a list of all chat rooms.

```
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda' id='disco2' to='chat.shakespeare.lit' type='get'>
      <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>
```

example result:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="disco2" from="chat.shakespeare.lit" to="hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">
        <item jid="example@shakespeare.lit" name="Example"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

However, I need to query only chat rooms that match a specific term.
Looking at the XMPP XML syntax, it looks like one of these XML queries should work:

```
<iq type="get" from="hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda" to="chat.shakespeare.lit" id="disco2">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search">
        <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="get">
            <field var="name">
                <value>*SEARCH*</value>
            </field>
        </x>
    </query>
</iq>
```

Or this:

```
<iq type="set" from="hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda" to="chat.shakespeare.lit" id="search2">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search">
        <item name="*SEARCH*"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

I have tried switching "get" to "set" and vice versa.
I have also tried removing the wildcard and making a literal search for a room I know exists.

Does anyone have an idea what the correct syntax is for searching for one or multiple names (Wildcarded) in the same query from the XMPP MUC service?

EDIT: My XMPP server supports the following features for the group chat service

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" from="chat.shakespeare.lit" to="hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
        <identity category="conference" name="Public Chatrooms" type="text"/>
        <identity category="directory" name="Public Chatroom Search" type="chatroom"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:search"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

Any ideas?
Anyone? I would settle for a way of getting a list of chat rooms that I have created?