# Correct syntax for searching XMPP server for email?

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I have an objective-c implementation of XMPP where I am trying to search for users. I use a predictable JID naming system where users JIDs are formed from the syntax 'fbFACEBOOK_ID'.

I tried initially to directly query to look for matching JIDs but found that XMPP doesnt seem to support that, so instead, I had users set their JID in their email field.

The following XML IQ works correctly when there is only query entered, but fails to get any results when there is more than one query. Is this not the correct syntax for searching for more than one term at once?

```
<iq type="set" from="hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda" to="search.shakespeare.lit" id="search2" xml:lang="en">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search"><email>*fb000000001*</email></query>
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search"><email>*fb000000002*</email></query>
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search"><email>*fb000000003*</email></query>
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search"><email>*fb000000004*</email></query>
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search"><email>*fb000000005*</email></query>
</iq>
```

See also: [XMPP Query Group Chat (MUC) directory using search term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133166/xmpp-query-group-chat-muc-directory-using-search-term)

EDIT: I  have tried using one query and multiple email elements instead with no luck 
EDIT2: So, it doesn't seem like this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<iq>` elements **MUST** have one and only one child element, so that won't work. [XEP 55: Jabber Search](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html) doesn't define any way to search for multiple terms specifically, so it seems that you are out of luck.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  A common request to have everyone in everyones contact list, which is already supported by many common servers under the name "shared rosters".

Comment: Is that not really inefficient, say if the server had 100k users and everytime a user logs on they download the full roster including everyone?

Comment: There exists what's called *roster versioning*, which allows clients to cache their roster.  [Section 2.6 of RFC 6121](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6121#section-2.6) has more info about that.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing in different queries, try it in a single query tag. It worked for me.

```
 <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search">

     <email>abc@gmail.com</email>
     <email>bbc@gmail.com</email>

 </query>
```